# Clickonce running application allow uninstall

Tags: c#

I have a c# application using framework 2.0 deployed as click once. While this application is still running, the user is allowed to uninstall and install a different version. Neither able to run the new version nor Install/uninstall.

Comment: Levisaxos: My question is Why is it allowed to uninstall an application which is running. I solved this by reinstalling the old version again.